# html link to pictures that are not published in u1

Tags: ubuntu-one, html

This may be a dumb question, but I would like to store my portfolio in U1 and on my own web server (running 12.04) have links in the html for my portfolio page that point and load the images from u1. I see how to do this if I publish the photo, but is there a way to do this without publishing?  TIA, Dante

Answer (score 1):

No, there is not. For files to be publicly viewable, they must be published.